# Prove that $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid -2 < x - y^2 < 8 \}$ is open.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

$$B := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid -2 < x-y^² < 8 \}$$

I have to show that this set is in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ (Borel set). I think it's obvious that $B$ is an open set, so I guess that's the way to go, however I can't figure out any way to do this. I tried to find a $r>0$ such that for any $(x,y) \in B$, there is a ball that is in $B$, but couldn't find any. I also tried to seperate the set into two sets, but it didn't work for me. Any hints or solutions?

Comment: Maybe try using some epsilon for a case like $x-y^2 = 8$?

Comment: Note that $B$ is the preimage of an open set under a continuous map $\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "know" the following fact:
$$
\text{if $f$ is continuous then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for any open $U \subseteq codomain(f)$},
$$
then the statement is easily proved, without any epsilon-delta fuss:

The function $f\colon (x,y)\mapsto x-y^2\colon \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ is continuous, and the interval $(-2,8)$ is open in $\Bbb R$, thus $B = f^{-1}((-2,8))$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$; hence $B \in \mathcal{B}(\Bbb R^2)$.

Comment: Yes, thought of it too, but wasn't sure how to use it exactly. I have another idea, but I'm not sure if it's right.

$$-2 < x - y^2 < 8 \Leftrightarrow -2 + y^2 < x < 8 + y^2$$

Then $y$ can be in $\mathbb{R}$, while x has then to verify the equation above, so we can say that that is the set described by:

$$]-2 + y^2, 8 + y^2[ \, \times \, ]-\infty, +\infty[ $$

which is an open set. Is that a valid explanation?

Comment: It isn't, because: what is $y$? It comes from the second set of the product (which is just $\Bbb R$). Your set is really $\bigcup_{y\in \Bbb R} (-2+y^2, 8+y^2) \times \{y\}$, and none of the sets $(-2+y^2, 8+y^2) x \{y\}$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$ so you can't conclude that their union is open. // PS It's incredibly difficult to read a cartesian product of intervals when you use Bourbaki notation $]a,b[$ !! The eye can't help but notice $[ \times ]$ right in the center, as if it were "a thing", which leads to an inevitable  "wtf?" moment.

Comment: What about:

$$\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}} \bigcup_{y \in \mathbb{R}} (-2+y^2, 8 + y^2) \times (y- \frac{1}{n}, y+ \frac{1}{n})$$

Would that work?

Comment: Ok no wait, that doesn't work. I wanted to take the intersection, but that wouldn't be an open set anymore (mixing open sets with algebras now. Damn it, brain!)

Comment: Using $\bigcap_n$ should work, yes. But: that defines a $G_{\delta}$ set, which of course is Borel, but is more complicated than an open set and thus gives a less "tight" bound on $B$ in terms its rank in the Borel hierarchy. Why makes things difficult? :)

Comment: I was wondering if the method worked, because a friend of mine proposed that answer with the cartesian product, which didn't really convince me. The intersection part was mine, and was mere curiosity, to see whether it is possible to go that far, but it's obviously too complicated, and far-fetched, compared to the above one. Thank you, I forgot to say.

Comment: You're quite welcome, & thank you. If you want to be impish, ask your friend to write out that proposed definition of $B$ as a standard set comprehension, i.e. using "set builder" notation.

Comment: oh you bet I will ^^

Answer (score 1):

For any topological space $X$ and any continuous functions $f:X\to R,\; g:X\to R ,$ and any $k\in R,$ the following are also continuous: $-f,\; kf,\; f+g, \; f-g, \;fg $ ( where $fg(p)=f(p)g(p).)$ (And if $f(p)\ne 0,$ then $1/f$ is continuous on a nbhd of $p.$) And constant function are continuous..... With $X=R^2$ and $f(x,y)=x, \; g(x,y)=y,$ and repeated applications of this, every polynomial $h(x,y)$  from $R^2$ to $R$ is continuous. So with $h(x,y)=x-y^2,$ the inverse, under $h$, of the open set $S=(-2,8)$, is open. Why? Because of the definition of continuity: $h$ is continuous iff the set $h^{-1}S =\{p :h(p)\in S\}$ is open whenever $S$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see myself expert in this area. I just follow the definitions.

$$-2<x-y^2<8$$

and for each $x_0$ and $y_0$ there must be $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ with a neighborhood in the way that

$$-2<(x_0+\epsilon)-(y_0+\delta)^2<8$$

or

$$-2-(x_0-y_0^2)<\epsilon-2\delta y_0-\delta^2<8-(x_0-y_0^2)$$

we define

$$r=\min(x_0-y_0^2+2,8-x_0+y_0^2)>0$$

$$-r<\epsilon-2\delta y_0-\delta^2<+r$$

Now, we have to show that the in-equation about allows a neighborhood for $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ at the same time.

I set the following limit for $\epsilon$

$$-\frac{r}2<\epsilon<+\frac{r}2$$

Then

$$-r-\epsilon<-2\delta y_0 -\delta^2<r-\epsilon$$

$$-\frac{r}2<\delta^2-2\delta y_0<+\frac{r}2$$

The left inequation gives
$$\delta>-y_0+\sqrt{y_0^2-\frac{r}2}$$

The right inequation gives

$$-y_0-\sqrt{y_0^2+\frac{r}2}<\delta<-y_0+\sqrt{y_0+\frac{r}2}$$

and together:

$$-y_0+\sqrt{y_0^2-\frac{r}2}<\delta<-y_0+\sqrt{y_0+\frac{r}2}$$

So, there is a neighborhood for both $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, hence there is a neighborhood for both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: That's not how you use $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, do you mean the method messy or you mean it is false?

Comment: I mean it's probably right - I haven't checked the details, because, as you say, it's messy. It's just a highly nonstandard use of the symbols $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. Usually they refer to the definition of continuity, which isn't how you're using them here. But you probably shouldn't listen to what I say; I'm an algebraist, not an analyst.